# Unable to properly reference class from another namespace

Tags: c++

I'm using an external library that has a class bplus_tree that is defined in a namespace bpt. The class declaration is below

```
// bpt.h
class bplus_tree {
public:
    bplus_tree(const char *path, bool force_empty = false);

// bpt.cc
bplus_tree::bplus_tree(const char *p, bool force_empty)
    : fp(NULL), fp_level(0)
{ code here }
```

I'm referencing it from another file main.cpp that has the following code

```
// main.cpp

#include "BPlusTree/bpt.h" // This is the correct path to the bpt.h file

bplus_tree tree("", false); // Error here
```

When I try and compile this with `g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++11`, I get the following error.

```
error: unknown type name 'bplus_tree'; did you mean 'bpt::bplus_tree'?
```

When I change `bplus_tree` to `bpt::bplus_tree`, however, I get the new error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "bpt::bplus_tree::bplus_tree(char const*, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in main_2-c3bbcc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations for a couple hours now, and I'm honestly not sure what's going on. Is it just something obvious that I am missing or what else am I not getting?

Comment: You're not passing `bpt.cc` to the compiler when you're linking the executable (hence "undefined symbol" - the linker can't find the definition for `bpt::bplus_tree`) Try running `g++ main.cpp bpt.cc -o main -std=c++11`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much for your help!